# Tensorflow doesn't converge for XOR

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I tried writing a simple XOR neural network but it never converges

I create a NN with 2 inputs, 2 hidden nodes and 1 output.

I use a relu on the first hidden layer and a softmax at the end to get the outputs.

In theory it should learn how to solve it and converge?

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# define placeholder for input and output
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4,2], name="x-input")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4,1], name="y-input")

# Configure weights and layers
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 2], -.01, .01))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2], -.01, .01))
hidden  = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x_,W) + b) # first layer.

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,1], -.1, .1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
hidden2 = tf.matmul(hidden, W2 + b2)
y = tf.nn.softmax(hidden2)

# Training function
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(hidden2))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(cross_entropy)

XOR_X = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
XOR_Y = [[0],[1],[1],[0]]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
# Train on the input data
for i in range(100):
    sess.run([cross_entropy, train_step], feed_dict={x_: XOR_X, y_: XOR_Y})
    print ('W1', sess.run(W))
    print('Output ', sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_: XOR_X, y_: XOR_Y}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistakes...

1. The W2 weights should be between -1 and 1 since they're not using a ReLu. Also the first layer weights use ReLu so I set them as positive to try avoid dead neurons.
2. Softmax makes no sense unless it's a 1 hot vector layer. Sigmoid makes more sense. Reading up on how Softmax works helps out.
3. Reduce sum should be done on y not hidden2
4. `hidden2 = tf.matmul(hidden, W2 + b2)` has brackets incorrectly. Should be `hidden2 = tf.matmul(hidden, W2) + b2`
5. -Log as an error function only works if you're trying to get the output to 1 not 0. This is because -log(1) = 0, and infinity when -log(0). This encourages output to go to 1 but not 0. Good for 1 hot vector not if you're trying to push an output to 0 for one input and 1 for another.
6. 2 neurons in the hidden layer does work. But it is very susceptible to randomness in initialization. Using extra neurons (10 instead of 2) makes this less susceptible to initialization errors.

The code below works. It uses a cost function that helps converge to 0 and to 1 for different inputs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# define placeholder for input, None as first argument means tensor can be any length
x_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4,2], name="x-input")
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4,1], name="y-input")

# Configure weights and layers
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2, 10], 0.001, .01))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
hidden  = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x_,W) + b) # first layer.

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([10,1], -1, 1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
hidden2 = tf.matmul(hidden, W2) + b2
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(hidden2)

# Training function + data
cost = tf.reduce_mean(( (y_ * tf.log(y)) +
((1 - y_) * tf.log(1.0 - y)) ) * -1)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

XOR_X = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
XOR_Y = [[0],[1],[1],[0]]

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
# Train on the input data
for i in range(100000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_: XOR_X, y_: XOR_Y})
    if i % 2000 == 0:
        print ('W1', sess.run(W))
        print('Output ', sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_: XOR_X, y_: XOR_Y}))
```